# Rails (postgres) query with jsonb array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

My Product model has a jsonb field `specs` (which we're managing using ActiveRecord's `store_accessor`). Many of my products' specs have a spec in that hash called `spec_options`.

Before now, this `spec_option` field was just text. Now it needs to be an array.

The scope used before now to query products for this field was this:

```
scope :with_spec_options, ->(spec_options) { 
    where("'#{spec_options}'::jsonb \? (specs->>'spec_option')") 
}
```

Ruby equivalent (just to help understand what this is doing):

```
select{ |product| spec_options.include?(product.specs['spec_option']) }
```

ActiveRecord equivalent (if `spec_option` were a regular column):

```
where(spec_option: spec_options)
```

However, now that `specs['spec_options']` is an array, I can't do that. I think I need to use postgres' `?|` jsonb operator, but I can't work out how to get the right side of this operation into the correct format.

Ruby equivalent:

```
def self.with_spec_options(spec_options)
    all.select{|product| 
        if product.specs['spec_options'].present?
            product.specs['spec_options'].any?{|option|
                spec_options.include?(option)
            }
        else
            false
        end
    }
end
```

Anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you want to use is the [`@>` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html), which tests whether your left-hand value contains the right-hand value. "Contains" works for both objects and arrays, so the following query would work:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE specs->'spec_options' @> '["spec1", "spec2"]';
```

Which I believe you can transform into ActiveRecord-compatible syntax like so:

```
scope :with_spec_options, ->(spec_options) { 
  where("specs->'spec_option' @> ?", spec_options.to_json) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was almost it. Both sides of the operation needed to be jsonb, so this worked:

`where("specs->'spec_option' @> ?::jsonb", spec_options.to_json)`

Comment: Scrap that, you don't need the extra ::jsonb conversion: 

`where("specs->'spec_option' @> ?", spec_options.to_json)`

Comment: Ugh, so I thought this was a solution, but it's not *quite* what I need. It needs to return results if _any_ of the queried options match. This answer only returns results with _all_ matching.

Comment: @Obversity: try this instead: `where("specs->'spec_option' ?| :options", options: spec_options)`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `where("specs->'spec_option' ?| array[:options]", options: spec_options)`. The interpolation into proper Postgres syntax is a bit tricky.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!